# Capture Image of ScaleSet Instance

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I have created an environment on scale set first instance, now I want to capture an image of that scale set instance (Protected from scale-in) so that I can create another scale set with that image with environment. Any way to capture or backup that instance of scale set in azure?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Azure CLI command `az image create` to capture the image from the scale set like this:

```
az image create -g group_name -n image_name --source instance_os_disk_resourceId --os-type xxxx
```

And you can use the command `az vmss list-instances` to get the OS disk resource ID of the instance. For example:

```
az vmss list-instances -g charlesVMSS -n azurevmss -o table --query "[].[instanceId, storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id]"
```